How to Filter an array with another array in excel?
I have a main array that i want to filter it and take some items out of it that is located in another array .
and i want the result to look like this ...

I tried this code but it just gives an error ...
=FILTER(B2:E6,NOT(G2:J6))

I don't know what to do

Here is one way of accomplishing the desired output using REDUCE() functions:


• Formula used in cell L2
=LET(
     α, B2:E6,
     IFNA(DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),LAMBDA(δ,φ,
     VSTACK(δ,FILTER(INDEX(α,φ,),
     ISNA(XMATCH(INDEX(α,φ,),INDEX(G2:J6,φ,))),"")))),1),""))


One more alternative:
=LET(
     α, B2:E6,
     δ, DROP(IFNA(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:E6)),LAMBDA(r,c,
        VSTACK(r,FILTER(INDEX(B2:E6,c,),
        COUNTIF(INDEX(G2:J6,c,),INDEX(B2:E6,c,))=0)))),""),1),
      IF(δ=0,"",δ))

